# Should we make tags for the different languages?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Recently, a user asked a [question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/6116/neural-network-returns-about-the-same-outputmean-for-every-input) in which I am unable to help (Or even refer) the OP as I do not know which language is being used.

So, my question is, should we make language tags ("python", "javascript", "java", etc) to help users in answering the question? I know we attempt to avoid implementation details, but every now and then one comes up, and some users are unable to help as they do not know what language the OP is using.

#### TL;DR

Should we implement language tags to help answer a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worry about the confusion between StackExchange AI and Stackoverflow. But as the code refers to Artificial Intelligence and these languages are becoming the tool of Data Scientists, I believe it is quite valid.